Best GPU for my Workstation
What would be the best GPU for my workstation? I have a Lenovo P520 with a W-2255 CPU, 64GB 2400T memory. Just wondering what card my CPU will not bottleneck. Currently I have a RTX2070 installed. I wanted to upgrade to a RTX 2080 TI or a RTX 3080. I searched hi and low to try and find out if my CPU would bottle neck these cards but never found a definitive answer.

"I searched hi and low to try and find out if my CPU would bottle neck these cards but never found a definitive answer." Bottlenecking may be somewhat relevant for gaming where both may be stressed simultaneously, but not for rendering, where the load is asymmetrically distributed
